# c# error after install project

Tags: c#, deployment, compiler-errors

I deploy a project using install shield limited edition, if I install it on my PC it works perfectly. If I bring it to another PC (doesn't have SQL sever) whenever I press some button that need to connect to database I got this exception.

[image]

Anyone who can fix this?

Comment: So you want to connect to an inexistent SQL Server? If you achieve it you will be rich!

Comment: I don't know Install shield - but I suppose it doesn't install SQL Server database :) You should use some local file database like SQLite, which can be easy "published" with your code or to use central database (to which all of the clients would connect)

Comment: sir @Piotr can you describe briefly  or give me link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with this recently!

My best bet is that you have one or two of these things happening. Either you have **ports not opened** that you need to have opened for your program to communicate with or (the most likely) that the **group policy** on the machine that you are installing to is blocking the application. I had this occur primarily with hashing.

This guy is not necessarily an easy fix. What I would do is open up **Windows Event Viewer** and read through the stack trace on the error and see which library threw the exception. Then I would open up the group policy and see if you can find that name in the policy.

Another idea is that it could very easily be a permission set that you have on your **SQL server** not allowing a computer to talk to it, but that is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses a local database(in local sql server), you should find a way to attach your database either together with your application or in your MS-SQL Server.
B/C in your attached picture it is saying: "The server was not found.."
So if you have a simple button like this, you should be able to reach your server by your connection string.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn ;
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }
```

Note: if you are using locally attached database, it is a must that you should install MS-SQL Server in your new deploying PC.

Comment: sir is there anyway to run application sql?

Comment: you mean an application with out installing SQL Server?, if so, yes only if you use a remote server (like your server connected in a network.)

Comment: i want to install on client pc.